# How do you turn off developer mode on an s5?

Tags: samsung, samsung-galaxy-s-5

I turned developer options 'off', but is there anything else that needs to be done? Not my phone so don't want to mess anything up :-)

Comment: I'm not sure what do you want, but AFAIK, you can't hide developer option after someone enabled it. So, the only thing you can do is just turn it off and never open that option again.

Comment: I've heard that there is a button in the upper or lower corners of the developer options menu to turn it off.

Answer (score 2):

You can actually hide the **Developer options** permanently from the menu until someone enables it again. Just follow this -

```
Menu > Settings > Apps > All apps > (find) Settings > Clear data > Confirm
```

Developers options will be turned off automatically although they are enabled by following the above step.

Comment: Would it not wipe the custom settings (under Settings) as well?

Comment: I've never tried (and I don't want to) for myself but I think you'll lose all other settings too. It's just a method to hide Developer options as OP is so concerned about messing with them.

Answer (score 0):

After Developer mode is disabled, that will put your phone back into the same state that it was in before Developer mode was enabled.  It will disable all developer options that could lead to security issues (Allowing ADB, etc.) and the slightly power draining options (show touch, running processes) that are open to developers.

However, as @Andrew T. points out, you won't be able to hide the developer options.  The only way to re-hide them is to do a factory reset (which probably isn't worth it).

Answer (score -1):

Yes, there is a way to hide it. But the options like USB debugging, if turned on, will  remain turned on.

**It'll only hide the developer option.**

Steps:

1. Go to Settings → Applications.
2. Swipe and go to All applications.There will be an app called 'Settings'
3. Click on it → 'Clear data'.

Now, the Settings app will  automatically close. Open Settings app again and Developer options should be gone.

It worked on my Android phone (running KitKat).

**Note** that it will only hide the options, but the settings would remain as it were before. For resetting the options, you need to do it manually.

Comment: You have just copied the answer MANI left in May.

Comment: @RoryAlsop I in the hindsight downvoted the answer at first but later realized that this answer has improved the other answer but the poster deliberately didn't or forgot to give credit to the original answerer. I once read that any answer that is better than the existing answers is always welcomed. Except the credit part, I guess the improvements are legit. However, I also think that improvements here could've been a comment to other answer, so you may be right too. :) Oh well, I made my edit and will let others to decide what to do.

Comment: I would suggest making the improvements to the existing answer would have been a much better idea. That is why SE is collaboratively edited.

Comment: @firelord Right. But the description of the question says that he had turned off the developer option already. So, there's now only one thing that Mani can do.... It's the thing that I answered.

Comment: However, I can't comment on questions due to lack of reputations.